# Wrong python packages path for opencv cmake installation

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, opencv3.0, virtualenvwrapper

I've been trying to follow the opencv installation steps from [pyimagesearch.com](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) with virtualenv. Everything works fine except for the packages path: it should be `/Users/JLee/Envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages` but it's configured as `lib/python2.7/site-packages`

In Python, `import cv2` works well in the global setting but doesn't work in the 'cv' virtual environment.

While following the steps from the site, I first proceeded without installing virtualenv, then realized I haven't installed it so I installed it later and followed the steps again. Could this be a problem?

```
 Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /Users/JLee/Envs/cv/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.10)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (ver 2.7.10)
--     numpy:                       /Users/JLee/Envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This is the code for cmake to configure the build:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ 
-D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/Users/JLee/Envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages \ 
-D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin \ 
-D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \ 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \ -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \ 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/JLee/Developer/opencv_project/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason it looks like CMake didn't automatically determine your `site-packages` directory for your virtual environment. That's not an issue though, because all you need to do is sym-link in the `cv2.so` file.

Find your `cv2.so` file on disk (based on your output, it seems to be in `lib/python2.7/site-packages`) and then sym-link into your Python virtual environment `site-packages` directory. From there, everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks this helped me as well. I had exactly the same problem as Jooyeon and couldn't import many of the modules, especially the ones in opencv_contrib, but this solved the problem.

Comment: This is more of a treatment for the symptoms than a cure. I'd prefer to know why CMake is having problems with my Conda install, but I'll settle for a working install from source. Thank you for getting me this far.