# Two versions of OpenCV in virtualenv, python

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

To my best I did not find a step by step tutorial on how to achieve what I want.

I would like to have two configurations for my projects: python2 with opencv2.4 and python3 with opencv3.1. For that I clone opencv and create a virtualenv following the tutorial from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/27/installing-opencv-3-0-for-both-python-2-7-and-python-3-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/) (just not raspberry PI and with CUDA, but it's just one more flag during configuration).

**Q1: How should I efficiently manage the installation of opencv when I create another virtualenv, for python3? Could I somehow link to various build folders?**

Removing the same build folder, checking out an opencv branch with the respective version and building it every time from scratch when I switch the virtualenv seems to be suboptimal solution.

(suppose, opencv is cloned into `/home/libraries/opencv/`)

**Q2: The tutorial describes in section 1 installation of various dependencies for opencv and python. It is before creating virtualenv. Can I still install for example python-dev and python-dev3 simultaneously or shall I overwrite things within virtualenv?**

---

Q3:
I managed to install and symlink properly both opencv versions with respective python versions within each of the virtualenv. However I don't fully understand cmake output:

Upon executing `cmake` (in virtualenv that uses python2.7 by default; opencv `git checkout 2.4.13` and opencv_contrib in master since there is none for opencv2.4), it takes python2.7 as interpreter. However packages path seems to not use virtualenv, why is that and why it still works?:

```
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/josh/.virtualenvs/tfpy2/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--     numpy:                       /home/josh/.virtualenvs/tfpy2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

While trying to use virtualenv with python3.4 (`git checkout 3.1.0`), cmake now seems to recognize two python versions, however seems to choose the wrong one 2.7 (but i somehow built successfully with the desired 3.4). Why does it find python3.4 within virtualenv and python2.7 not, plus why chooses the wrong python for build?:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/josh/.virtualenvs/tfpy3/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so (ver 3.4.3)
--     numpy:                       /home/josh/.virtualenvs/tfpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.4/site-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
```

(I am aware that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291500/i-have-2-versions-of-python-installed-but-cmake-is-using-older-version-how-do) is some solution, but isn't the main idea of virtualenv to avoid such problems automatically? Also, it seems to be similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500617/wrong-python-packages-path-for-opencv-cmake-installation), but by me if the wrong version of python was recognized/used in compilation, so cannot simply symlink the built library.)

Answer (score 1):

A1: You may reuse OpenCV sources as follows. First, you build OpenCV 2.4, is a way similar to that you referenced, but you do `git checkout 2.4.13` instead of 3.1.0 for both opencv and opencv_contrib.

Once you built and installed (with make install) version 2.4, you then delete build folder, do `git checkout 3.1.0`, configure build, so it uses Python 3. Build and install again. At this point you should have two OpenCV versions built and installed on your computer.

A2: virtualenv is all about python modules or python bindings for libraries. Note, how tutorial uses virtualenv: you install numpy in a virtualenv and you create a link to cv2.so built to support python version for this environment.

Comment: thanks! I'm happy to read your solution! Meanwhile i encountered a problem which I updated in the main question to keep the post clean. Could you please have a look and update your answer?

Comment: Also, Let me just reassure that I know what runs under the hood. Essentially all the dependencies are needed in OpenCV to just build the cv2.so library. Make install copied then the .so file to site-packages of respectively python2.7 and python3.4 depending on which virtualenv I work on. So I can freely remove then the cloned repository, yes?
What I don't understand is why numpy was installed in virtualenv, not before? What if I had numpy and/or OpenCV installed out of virtualenv, will that be overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) for Python development. Its [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) is for IoT devices like Raspberry Pi.

Anaconda does support virtual environment through its `conda-env` package and config. With `conda-env`, you can run multiple copies and versions of Python. Install OpenCV through `conda install` which will download the Python package from its [Anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/raspberrypi/repo?label=main&type=conda&page=2) package repository once you registered. That would reduce a lot of hassles on downwload, package dependency and installaiton. For package not available in Anaconda Cloud, any `pip install` supported python packages can be installed to Anaconda. There is a learning curve but not too difficult to pick up.

Hope this help.

*Disclaimer: I'm not with Anaconda, am just an user of it.*

Comment: thanks a lot! However by this post I am not only looking for a quick solution but to understand what is happening under the hood.